# Trouble starting manual job through Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am trying to start a manual job using the Gitlab API, but I get the following error:

```
$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN_API}" "https://***/api/v4/projects/226/jobs/1993191"
{"id":1993191,"status":"manual", ...}
$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN_API}" "https://***/api/v4/projects/226/jobs/1993191/play"
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
```

As you can see, fetching the job works fine and the job is in the "manual" state but the `/play` endpoint does not work. The token I am using has all the rights, i.e. I ticked all the boxes when creating it. The Gitlab instance is self-hosted and running version 15.8.3-ee.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `play` endpoint requires a `POST` request:

```
$ curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN_API}" "https://***/api/v4/projects/226/jobs/1993191/play"
{"id":1997454,"status":"pending",...
```